# How to configure support for cmd key in terminal (neovim)

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, iterm2

This question has been raised several times in several places.
You can't map `cmd` out of the box when neovim is used in terminal.

Most of the answers were you can't or try karabiner.

There is this solution
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/176#issuecomment-37070131

Configuring "CSI u" is not enough, as I understand.
And it seems that I need a parsing lib, but it refers to a deprecated one.

I don't know if installing it would be enough. Anyone did it successfully?

I am with ITerm2, but any other terminal will do.

Comment: so what problem are you trying to solve exactly? I thought neovim includes the libtermkey library, so that shouldn't be an issue. Vim now has support for xterms `modifyotherkeys` setting, so both solutions should work.

Comment: It doesn't work. I didn't know it should have worked. I tried latest version of neovim ,iterm2 with -u NONE.  <c-v> doesn't recognize cmd keys.

Comment: that's my understanding, since neovim include leonerd libtermkey library. But it's a known issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11551

Comment: MacVim supports `<D->` mappings AFAIK

Comment: The known issue seems to be only for cmd-v. I can't map these keys either.

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11583 if it works for you, let me know what terminal and OS